# MSSQL, Encoding and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, encoding, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using a database with a web-application. The problem is that special characters get encoded wrong on the website after retrieving them with a `SELECT` statement.

On the website I'm using `UTF-8` encoding. On the DB `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

How can I solve this? I can't change the encoding on the DB because there are several other applications using it, but changing the encoding on the website could be an approach.

Thanks

---

**EDIT**:

I could convert return-strings with the method `string utf8_encode ( string $data )`. It isn't a very nice approach, is there a way to manage this globally?

Comment: You can change the encoding of the DB tables, you don't need to change the encoding of the entire DB. That way you're not effecting the other DB applications and solving your encoding issue.

Comment: But the tables are also being shared by different applications...